# How to open the first notification message

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a GcmIntentService class,
This is the code:

```
    public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static  int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    int numMessages ;
    Boolean isSaveDetails ;
    Boolean isRememberMe ;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
       GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        //The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
         //in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
             * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
             * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
             */
           if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
               // sendNotification(extras.toString());
           } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                //sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
           // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
           } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification( extras);
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
       GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
  }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(Bundle extras) {
        String msg = URLDecoder.decode(extras.getString("message"));
        String msg1="";
        String sender = extras.getString("sender");
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String type= extras.getString("messageType");
        PendingIntent contentIntent ;
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE); 
        isRememberMe= pref.getBoolean("rememberMe", false); 

        if(type.equals("add_contacting")||type.equals("update_contacting_inspector")||type.equals("update_contacting_admin"))
        {
            Intent demoactivity;
             msg1=msg;
             String contactingId= extras.getString("contactingId");
             boolean foregroud=true;
            try {
                foregroud = new ForegroundCheckTask().execute(getApplicationContext()).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             if(!isRememberMe&&foregroud==false)//login page will open only if the app isn't on  Foreground
                demoactivity = new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
             else
                demoactivity = new Intent(this,Show_Contacting_page.class);
            demoactivity.putExtra("calling-activity", moveBetweenActivities.GCM_INTENT_SERVICES);
            demoactivity.putExtra("message",msg);
            demoactivity.putExtra("sent_from",sender); 
            demoactivity.putExtra("contactingId",contactingId); 
            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,demoactivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       }

        else
        {
            msg1=msg;
            Intent demoactivity = new Intent(this,Show_Contacting_page.class);
            demoactivity.putExtra("message",msg);
            demoactivity.putExtra("sent_from",sender);  
            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,demoactivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.rh_logo)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_message_title))
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg1))
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        numMessages = 0;
         mBuilder.setContentText(msg1)
          .setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(++NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());



        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();

    }
```

My problem is: if the app get two or more notifications and they all displaied on actionBar,
when the user is clicking on the first notification message in the actionBar the last notification is opened,

(I think that the first notification messages are not saved.)

Can someone explain to me what the problem with my code? And what to change in the code?

Comment: Problem is, you are using same notification id. Which override your previous notification. try to use different notification id.

Comment: I'm using ++ for the notificationId isn't it correct?

Comment: So what the problem? I didnt understood...